# Energy meter data read and write to display in serial port using COM 

Tags: java, serial-port

I am using energy meter.  How to that meter data reading and writing code in Java?

It will be power line node to send and transferring the data it will be convert the concentrator in RS232 to display in serial port. Windows using Java.

Output example in reading meter value is:

```
A 00 09 14 03 81 0C 03 10 03 00 30 B0 03 3A 00   :.........0°.:.
09 14 03 81 02 03 10 03 00 30 B1 2D 3A 00 09 14   ........0±-:...
03 81 02 03 10 03 00 04 B0 FA 3A 00 09 14 5C 81   .......°ú:...\
02 03 10 03 00 04 B0 FA
```

Comment: So uh...  That's a fun bunch of random data.  What exactly is the meaning in it?

Comment: Which meter is it? Do you have any documentation of the protocol?

Comment: Should that first `A` be `3A`?

Answer (score 0):

For reading and writing data to a serial port under windows i recomend using rxtx

http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Main_Page

There are samples for reading and writing:

http://rxtx.qbang.org/wiki/index.php/Using_RXTX

There is a com api from oracle, but the actual version has only implementations for Solaris SPARC, Solaris x86, and Linux x86

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/index-jsp-141752.html

I used an older version for windows, but it is hard to find and has some shortcommings (e.g. didn't found ports above com4 without 'helping', has problems with spaces in path to dll and so on)

Comment: i am asking how to write the code in read and write the data in energy meters.plz send it the full coding.